# Is MSVCRT's implementation of fprintf() thread safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, printf, msvcrt

It seems that [glibc's implementation of fprintf() is thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594851/is-glibcs-implementation-of-fprintf-thread-safe), but is that so for Microsoft's CRT, as well?

By thread-safe, I don't mean just crashing, but also that if multiple threads (in the same process) call `fprintf()`, the texts will not be mixed.

That is, for example, if thread A calls `fprintf(stdout, "aaaa");` and thread B calls `fprintf(stdout, "bbbb");` it's guaranteed not to mix to become `aabbaabb`.

Is there such a guarantee?

Comment: Strange: text still seems to be mixed: https://github.com/git/git/commit/116d1fa6c693e13321dc4c6abe256ca7878e55a5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.  In the multithreaded runtime libraries, every stream has an associated lock.  This lock is acquired at the beginning of any call to a printf function and not released until just before that printf function returns.

This behavior is required by C11 (there was no concept of "threads" in standard C until C11).  C11 §7.21.2/7-8 states:

> Each stream has an associated lock that is used to prevent data races when multiple
>   threads of execution access a stream, and to restrict the interleaving of stream operations performed by multiple threads. Only one thread may hold this lock at a time. The lock is reentrant: a single thread may hold the lock multiple times at a given time.
>
> All functions that read, write, position, or query the position of a stream lock the stream before accessing it. They release the lock associated with the stream when the access is complete.

Visual C++ does not fully support C11, but it does conform to this requirement.  A couple of other Visual C++-specific comments:

As long as you are not defining [`_CRT_DISABLE_PERFCRIT_LOCKS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235356.aspx) (which only works with the statically-linked runtime libraries, libcmt.lib and friends) or using [the _nolock-suffixed functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235386.aspx), then most operations on a single stream are atomic.

If you require atomicity across multiple operations on a stream, you can acquire the lock for a file yourself by acquiring and releasing the stream lock yourself using [`_lock_file`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8w5bsb4f.aspx) and [`_unlock_file`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2z49acd.aspx).

Comment: How far back does this go? For example, was `fprintf()` thread-safe in VC6's multithreaded CRT?

Comment: Yes, this is the case in the VC6 multithreaded runtime libraries.  VC6 is the oldest version of the sources that I have readily available; I'm not entirely sure when this was implemented.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis You state "Yes. In the multithreaded runtime libraries, every stream has an associated lock."  How do I know if the library I am using is a multithreaded runtime library?

Comment: @Trisped All of the runtime libraries are multithreaded since Visual Studio 2005.  See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/154753 for details about past versions.

Comment: Any link to MSDN to support this? This page doesn't say anything about thread safety and interleaving of the output: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh07fe2.aspx